# Low correlation coefficient, low p-value. Is there an alternative/supporting analysis?

Tags: correlation, post-hoc

I have ran a series of (Spearman) correlation analyses. The resulting statistics result in low correlation coefficients (i.e. <0.01) and low p-values (indicating significance). Is there post hoc, supporting or alternative analysis that could considered to support (or deny) this statistical analysis?

As an FYI, the data does not conform to the assumptions of linear models regardless of transformation, therefore linear modeling (i.e. regression) is not possible.

---

@NickCox, You are correct it is a very large sample size. While I don't doubt that it is significantly correlated there really is no predictability throughout the continuum of values. Below is an example of the data, the Y axis is log transformed to display the data.

[image]

Also provided are the diagnostic regression plots.
[image]

Comment: This is possible with very large sample sizes. The correlation can be very small but a significance test can assure you that it is not zero. There is no inherent contradiction here. Either way, substantively Spearman correlation appears to be a dead end, so the next thing to do is think about something else.  As for your second paragraph, show (meaning graph) (some of) the data if you want an opinion, but it's likely that the conclusion is unwarranted: linear models cover a much wider range than is evident when you first meet them.

Comment: Thanks for the graph. As I see no hint there of a monotonic relationship, Spearman correlation does appear pointless as well as negligible. There should be some science to guide you here. Otherwise smoothing your response as a function of temperature may discern a little structure. Is this atmospheric chemistry? plant physiology? ??: in the latter case, I might expect a unimodal response, a hump in plain terms. Presumably the temperatures are Celsius and some maximum around 25$^\circ$C may be genuine or wishful thinking on my point.

Comment: I agree spearman correlation is pretty much a dead end and typically hate using it in any analysis. Thanks for the assistance. This relationship is water column pCO2 versus water column temperature  within a wetland (so a mix of atmospheric chemistry and plant physiology).

Comment: Try smoothing then. Lowess|loess|locfit, splines, local polynomials, any method you like.